# I am calling the Jquery function from code behind in asp net but it showing for one time only not for other

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
        ServerMonitoringDetails objServerMonitorings = new ServerMonitoringDetails();
        objServerMonitorings = ServerMonitoringBusinessManager.GetAllIpDetailsByIpAddress();
        StringBuilder sbPhysicalMemory = new StringBuilder();
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("Physical Memory");
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("<div class=\"MemoryFixed\">");
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("<a href=\"ServerMonitoringGraphDetails.aspx?Ip=KHUSHVINDER-PC\">KHUSHVINDER-PC</a>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.divPhysicalMemory, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>bind(div1,50,200);</script>", false);
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("<div id=\"div1\">");
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("</div>");
        sbPhysicalMemory.Append("</div>");
        divPhysicalMemory.InnerHtml = sbPhysicalMemory.ToString();
        StringBuilder sbVirtualMemory = new StringBuilder();
        sbVirtualMemory.Append("Virtual Memory");
        sbVirtualMemory.Append("<div class=\"MemoryFixed\">");
        sbVirtualMemory.Append("<a href=\"ServerMonitoringGraphDetails.aspx?Ip=KHUSHVINDER-PC\">KHUSHVINDER-PC</a>");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.divVirtualMemory, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>bind(divVM,100,200);</script>", false);
        sbVirtualMemory.Append("<div id =\"divVM\">");
        sbVirtualMemory.Append("</div></div>");
        divVirtualMemory.InnerHtml = sbVirtualMemory.ToString();
```

hi this is my above code i am calling same function  twice in code behind but not working

Comment: i am calling the twice the jquery function
 but it not working if working it giving the same value across the all progress bar

Comment: function bind(id, current, target) {
            var $progressbar = $(id).progressbar();            
            var value = (current / target) * 100
            $progressbar
                    .progressbar("value", value)
                    .removeClass("beginning middle end")
                    .addClass(value < 50 ? "end" : value < 90 ? "middle" : "beginning");

        }

Comment: above is my Jquery function

Comment: well if you are calling the function twice with the same vars `bind(div1,50,200);` obviously its going to show same thing...

Comment: i calling with different parameter u can see with different id also

Comment: i see, you have updated the question after i commented... so let me understand, the function is being called twice, and it does the same thing both times?

Comment: yes my Issue is yet not resolved

Comment: do you receive any errors in the developer console? (F12 in most browsers) are you certain that the function is indeed being called 2 times? try putting an alert or a `console.write("test")` in the beginning of the function to see if it is indeed being called twice

Comment: no dear not giving error i checked ...

Answer (score 0):

Having understood from @banana's interpretation that it works occasionally, 
@user3840910 please check your usage of

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

The third parameter for that method should be an unique identifier for the script being registered.

Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx

Also @user3840910, it would be a good practice to format your scripts while posting and not miss semicolons at the end of lines in javasript.

Comment: 1) he said it works occasionally, so your first point is invalid. 2) javascript has ASI, so your second point is invalid too.

Comment: @banana i don't see where he mentioned it works ocassionally.. if you want to help please create a conversation with author rather than going bananas on the answers

Comment: " if working it giving the same value across the all progress bar" as per op's first comment under his post